# Folders in umbraco 4

Tags: umbraco

Is there a way to simply create folders in umbraco 4 for the purpose of organizing content?  I've searched forums and did not find a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an area where the documentation is somewhat lacking, however it is perfectly doable:

Create a document type called something like "Content Folder". (You can't use Folder as it's already in use in the system).

Give the new doc type the following property:

Name: Redirect to

Alias: umbracoRedirect

Type: ContentPicker

The important bit there is the Alias: umbracoRedirect. This is one of the undocumented built in umbraco features. It basically redirects one node to another (making it act like a folder).

If you want to hide the folder from the menu then you'll need to add another one of those undocumented properties: umbracoNaviHide, which is used in the default XSLT navigaiton examples.

More info: http://www.umbraco.org/documentation/books/converting-existing-site-to-umbraco/creating-folders

Comment: Will the above solution work without changing the url of the sub page?

Comment: I am looking for a similar functionality. I want several Content Folders and each Content folder might have one or more contents. Will this solution is still valid for my case?